# Equation involving continued fractions.

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I'm not sure if my solution is right, but I'm wondering about the equation:
$$
x = 1 + \frac 1{x + \frac 1{x+ \frac 1{x+\frac 1{x+ \frac 1{x + \ldots}}}}}
$$
I rewrite this equation in form:
$$
x = 1+\frac 1{x}
$$
And this is the golden ratio.
But I'm confused about transition from the continued fraction to this one. I'm not sure that when I replace the first $x$ in denominator I'm able to sum continued fractions. And maybe I should get something like
$$
x = 1 + \frac 1{1 + \frac 2{x+ \frac 1{x+\frac 1{x+ \frac 1{x + \ldots}}}}}
$$

Comment: The resulting equation is not $x=1+\frac{1}{x}.$ It is $$x=1+\frac{1}{(x-1)+x}$$ You can't turn the $1$ into $x.$

Answer (score 1):

Your 'rewrite' is incorrect; $[x;x,x,x,\ldots]$ (to use the [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Motivation_and_notation) in which $[a;b,c,\ldots] = a+\dfrac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c+\ldots}}$) is not the same as $[1;x,x,x,\ldots]$, so you can't simply say that $x=1+\frac1x$. Instead, since $[x;x,x,\ldots]$ $= [1;x,x,\ldots]+x-1$, the equation that you get is that $x=1+\frac1{x+(x-1)}$ $=1+\frac1{2x-1}$. Can you take it from here?

**ETA**: I should note that even after you solve the equation for $x$ given by 'collapsing' the fraction, the problem isn't entirely done; since the equation here is improper, we're not immediately
guaranteed that an $x$ that solves the collapsed equation solves the original one. Fortunately, in this case we can look at the value of $x$ we get and see that the continued fraction that results is convergent.

Comment: You mean that we can do this by proving the existence of limit of sequence: 
$$
1, 1+\frac1{3/2} , \dots
$$
And that this limits is $\frac 3{2}$?

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO Exactly that. (Though it's probably slightly easier to show that the limit of the sequence $3/2, 3/2+\dfrac{1}{3/2}, \ldots$ is $2$, which is of course equivalent.)

Comment: yes, for your suggestion we consider $f(x)=\frac 3{2}+\frac 1{x}$. Which is clearly contraction map in the neighbourhood of $\frac 3{2}$ (since mean value theorem + $\vert f'(x) \vert < 1$) Therefore we have unique fixed point. So, we need to find such $a$, for which $f(a) = a$. Solving equation gives us that $a=2$ Then we just need to $1+\frac 1{2}$ to obtain $\frac 3{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Yout equation $x=1+\frac{1}{x}$ is wrong.

If $y=x-1$ then $$
y=\cfrac{1}{(y+1)+\cfrac{1}{(y+1)+\cfrac{1}{(y+1)+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}$$

Or $y=\frac{1}{(y+1)+y}.$

You get $2y^2+y-1=0$ or $y=\frac{-1\pm 3}{4}=-1,\frac{1}{2}.$

So $x=0,\frac{3}{2}.$ But $x=0$ is absurd, so $x=3/2.$